# Importing dispatch actions to React Component assistance

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am having trouble importing a dispatch action. The compiler is complaning that :

> Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>' has no property 'onShowError' and no string index signature.

`const { onShowError, error, errorMessage } = this.props` this is the code that is causing the problem.

I understand there is something wrong with my imports and how React extends the Component, etc but I just can't find the solution. I'm new to TypeScript let alone JavaScript. I just cannot figure out where something is going wrong.

I have tried creating my own interface CustomProps and declaring onShowError is a function but does not work. `Not Assignable to {}`

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Dispatch, Action } from "redux"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { AppState } from "reducers"

import { showError } from "data/error_handler"

import Snackbar from "material-ui/Snackbar"
import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton"

class ErrorHandler extends React.Component {
  hideErrorPopup = () => {
    this.setState({
      error: false,
    })
  }

  public render() {
    const { onShowError, error, errorMessage } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton
          onClick={onShowError}
          label="Toggle ErrorHandler"
        />
        <Snackbar
          bodyStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ffa000", marginBottom: "5px" }}
          open={error}
          message={errorMessage}
          autoHideDuration={5000}
          onRequestClose={this.hideErrorPopup}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  errorMsg: state.errorRedux.errorMessage,
  error: state.errorRedux.error,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
  return {
    onShowError: () => dispatch(showError()),
  }
}

export default connect<any>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ErrorHandler)
```

`Reducer.ts`

```
import { ErrorHandlerProps, ActionTypes } from "./"

const initialState: ErrorHandlerProps = {
  error: false,
  errorMessage: "",
}

export default (
  state: ErrorHandlerProps = initialState,
  action: ActionTypes
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SHOW_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
      }
  }
}
```

`Interface.ts & index.ts`

```
export interface ErrorHandlerProps {
  error: boolean
  errorMessage: string
}
import reducer from "./reducer"
export { reducer }
export * from "./actions"
export * from "./interfaces"
```

`actions.ts`

```
export type ActionTypes = {
  type: "SHOW_ERROR"
  error: boolean
  errorMessage: string
}

export const showError = (): ActionTypes => ({
  type: "SHOW_ERROR",
  error: true,
  errorMessage: "[ACTIONS]",
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to explicitly specify the shape of your component:

```js
class myClass extends React.Component<PropShape, StateShape>
```

To get the props working, provide the types of your props (which includes your component's actual props, and the props injected by `connect`: `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`).  In this case, you only need the injected props:

```js
class ErrorHandler extends React.Component<
    ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> 
    & ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>
> {

    ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  errorMsg: state.errorRedux.errorMessage,
  error: state.errorRedux.error,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
  return {
    onShowError: () => dispatch(showError()),
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ErrorHandler)
```

You'll probably also want to include the shape of your state, if you truly intend to keep a separate local component state, although I'm not sure what your final intention there is:

```js
class ErrorHandler extends React.Component<
    ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> 
    & ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>,
    IState> {
    ...
}

interface IState {
    error: boolean;
}
```

See https://github.com/sw-yx/react-typescript-cheatsheet for some common use cases for using React with TypeScript.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply. The information provided helped tremendously. I suspected the problem lay in the imports or the component declarations, I just couldn't figure it out. You are right to question the local states relevancy. I should just update the root state.
Although now I'm presented with `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Pick<{ errorMessage: string; error: boolean; } & { onShowError: () => ActionTypes; }, "onShowError" | "errorMessage" | "error">>': onShowError, errorMessage, error` referencing the imported component in App.tsx

Comment: Must I declare the information being passed in when importing the component to other pages?

Comment: Without a lot of context to go on, I would suspect it's your export: `export default connect<any>(...)`.  Try changing it to `export default connect(...)`.  Now that you've defined your component types, you shouldn't need the `any` hammer for your connect.  You shouldn't need to care about types for the most part when importing from another component.

Comment: You were spot on. Only thing for me to do now is conditionally render the popup as it is searching for information instantly. Thank you so much @Dylan you have helped me so much I can't thank you enough

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to quickly get around ts' complaint, the `as any` trick will do:

```js
const { onShowError, error, errorMessage } = this.props as any
```

To address this properly, you need to pass the CustomProps to your Component:

```js
interface CustomProps {
  onShowError: Function;
  error: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;
}

class ErrorHandler extends React.Component<CustomProps> {
  hideErrorPopup = () => {
    this.setState({

// ...
```